# Read whole file at once into an array

Tags: arrays, perl, file

I had read somewhere about the following method to read the whole file into a Perl array at once,

```
open my $file, '<', $filePath or die "Error: Unable to open file : $!";
my @fileData = <$file>;
close $file;
```

I suppose the size of the array is only limited by the available system memory. I wanted to know how exactly this works in the background, since there are no loops involved here to read the file line by line and feed them into the array.

Comment: What is there to say?  In array context, as provided by `my @fileData`, the `<>` operator reads lines into the array with an implicit loop.  It works.  Occasionally, it is useful. Perl has a couple of mottos.  One is TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It.  Another is DWIM — Do What I Mean; at least, Perl does this more than many languages, provided you know what you're asking for.  This is a piece of dwimmery.

Comment: `s/array(?=\s+context)/list/ if $nitpick;`

Comment: [Input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f), and file handle context ([scalar vs list](https://eval.in/98898)) define how reading should behave.

Comment: You should probably specify how detailed information you want about this, and why you want to know. This is a rather common Perl idiom, using list vs scalar context to get different results from a function.

Comment: @TLP What I wanted to know was partially answered in the first comment itself, by Jonathan, and later by mpapec, but what I really wanted to know was how exactly this 'implicit loop' works (logically) when the script is executed. Asking just out of curiosity.

Comment: @JTG : Consider using [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie::File) instead to avoid memory-hogging and utilize array functionality

Comment: @Jonathan, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wish is my command — a comment transferred to an answer, with a mild correction en route.

> What is there to say? In <s>array</s> list context, as provided by `my @fileData`, the `<>` operator reads lines into the array with an implicit loop. It works. Occasionally, it is useful.
>
> Perl has a couple of mottos. One is TMTOWTDI — There's More Than One Way To Do It. Another is DWIM — Do What I Mean; at least, Perl does this more than many languages, provided you know what you're asking for. This is a piece of dwimmery.

Answer (score 0):

[`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) is the Perl 5 built-in function that is implementing the `<EXPR>` operator. It has different behaviour in scalar and list context.